# ASp.Net MVC Core 2. Does any button fires submit in a form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to know if this behaviour is correct:
in a ASP.NET MVC Core 2 project i have a form with just one button. If i click on that button a submit of the form is fired. Is that correct? 
An if it is, how can i use a button for other matters inside a form?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
   <button>OK</button>    
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

The OK button does the same as the Input submit.

Here is the controller action:

```
[Route("/profile")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(UserViewModel user)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user.UserTypes = UserType.GetUserTypes();
        return View(user);
    }
    return Content("OK");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Button tag has a type property. By omitting it, you're subjected to browser's default behavior, wich is, in most cases, to consider submit as the default type for the button tag. You have 3 options to this property. type="button" makes it a non-submit clickable one. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp